# A graph with 10 vertices and 16 edges

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, terminology

Under which name has this graph been investigated?

[image]

Which characterizations of it are there? ("It's the unique graph with...")

Note that the graph is triangle-free and there is a planar embedding of the graph onto the sphere:

[image]

**Background**

The factorized rule space is of main importance in the study of elementary cellular automata (ECA). The full (unfactorized) rule space of ECAs is the 8-dimensional hypercube where two out of the 256 rules are adjacent when their Hamming distance is 1. As a graph the factorized rule space has equivalence classes* of rules as vertices which are adjacent when there is a pair of equivalence class members with Hamming distance 1. There are 88 such equivalence classes and the factorized rule space looks like this a force-directed graph:

[image]

Carefull investigation reveals that this graph has seven disjoint induced subgraphs, three of which are isomorphic to the 4-dimnsional hypercube and the other four are isomorphic to the graph in question (let me call it "the ball graph"), in other words: The factorized rule space of elementary cellular automata consists of three copies of the 4-dimensional hypercube (with 16 vertices) and four copies of the ball graph (with 10 vertices) which are specifically linked to each other.

Here you find one of the ball graphs highlighted:

[image]

And here one of the hypercubes:

[image]

What's more: the rule space has this overall structure with links between subgraphs only as indicated:

[image]

I hope this is enough motivation to consider the ball graph in its own right.

- Two rules are equivalent when they arise from each other by swapping direction (left/right) and/or color (black/white).

Comment: Most $10$-vertex graphs have never been investigated under any name. Does this graph have any features that would make it worth studying? Both Mathematica and House of Graphs know only one named graph with $10$ vertices, $16$ edges, and no triangles: the complete bipartite graph $K_{2,8}$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, I'm glad you asked for the relevance of this graph. I added some background to the original post.

Comment: So it's basically the edges of an octahedron, but where four edges that form a 4-cycle have had an extra vertex inserted.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: Yes, that's a way to describe it.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another drawing of the graph (thanks to @JaapScherphuis):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer to the question, but since there is no way to insert a picture in the comments, I put it here.

This is how this graph looks more clear. Of course there is nothing remarkable in it, but this drawing makes it look like a stylized eye.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what looks clear is in the eye [sic!] of the beholder. In my eyes my drawing is clearer (because it's more symmetric). Thanks anyway.

Comment: It seems to me useful to have different drawings of the same object in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully you will see a structural resemblance between the extended octahedral graph (top/left) and the 4-dimensional hypercube (bottom/middle): you may see a 3x3 grid with some center vertices doubled (18/54, 130/154) or quadrupled (2/26/38/62):

[image]

[image]

The extended octahedral graph is the graph that one gets when in the 4-dimensional hypercube the vertices 130/154, 34/58, 6/30, 3/27, 2/26 and 38/62 are collapsed. So it's **the collapsed 4-dimensional hypercube** in a sense.

In turn, the 3x3 square grid is the collapsed extended octahedral graph.

[image]

(Follow-up question: Which graph is the 4-dimensional hypercube the collapsed version of?)